# What is unit of parameter value in onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) method of View Class?

Tags: android, view

Can Any body let me know what is the unit of parameter of
 onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) this View Class Method.

I print the log it return me 1073742144,-2147483251 respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value is a combination of mode and size. Use `View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec)` to get the mode (one of `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY`, `MeasureSpec.AT_MOST` and `MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED`); what you probably want to know is `View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)`, the size in pixels.

See also the [source code of MeasureSpec](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/View.java&l=9019).

Comment: thanks, so when onMeasure(...) called it return the size of screen in pixel...am I right?

Comment: Yes, `onMeasure()` and all other measure-related functions work with pixels.